# Can I store an XML file inside a jar file?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I built an Jar using Maven.
The behavior I am trying to implement is: when the user uses the command create , I want to store an XML file inside a a folder of the jar. Is it possible to do it?

[image]

Let's say this is a project and I added the jar of the migration tool to it.
I want to be able to see and edit the properties file

Comment: Yes, absolutely. By default everything that's in your `src/main/resources` will be placed in your JAR file.

Comment: Put the file into `src/main/resources` and the result will be having the file in the root of the jar. If you like to have it in a folder you have to create a folder in `src/main/resources/FOLDER`...

Comment: @khmarbaise but I want to store it after compiling the jar

Comment: @khmarbaise what about a fetch jar?

Comment: @Fabio: so you want to modify the jar file while your code is running? That's a bad idea and not usually done, it's better to store your data elsewhere. It's not entirely impossible, though. Also: what do you mean by "fetch jar"?

Comment: @GenerousBadger my project is a tool for migration  that will be used in another projects. So if I find a way to add it to the other projects and be capable of editing it. I heard about fetch jar

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: your build creates an original jar file (let's call it `original.jar`) and then you have "some step" that modify that jar file by adding some (probably generated?) file to it? So that `modified.jar` is then used in other projects, right? Why not just have a config file at some place instead of including it in the jar? Is that tool used during the build of  the other projects?

Comment: @GenerousBadger I think I explained myself wrong. I'll try to be more concise
1- I built a migration tool 
2- The migration tool will be used in another projects
3-It has some things that need to be altered like for example migration files and the file with the database information
4-I built a jar using maven
5-I need a way to make those changes

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. But what I don't understand is why is there a strict requirement to bundle the modified migration files and database information *inside* the tool? If they are specific to the target environment, shouldn't they be handled there? It seems unusual to modify the tool itself instead of shipping it with configuration files. I would expect the necessary files to be something like `migration-tool.jar` and `my-project-config.zip` which contains all the configuration files bundled into one.

Comment: @GenerousBadger but the files that need to modified are configuration files(application.properties). It probably would be a good idea to leave my configuration as comment so that the users have an example

Comment: @GenerousBadger I posted a draw with the behavior I want

Answer (score 0):

> 3-It has some things that need to be altered like for example
> migration files and the file with the database information

Not 100% sure if I understood your requirements correctly, but I've implemented some utility classes which support:

- default config in JAR
- config in installation directory
- config in user directory
- simple command line arguments/ switches support
- and more...

Maybe this helps.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException, MissingPropertyException, Exception {
    CommandLineArgs commandLineArgs = CommandLineArgs.parseCommandLineArgs(args);
    DromblerClientStarter<DromblerClientConfiguration> main = new DromblerClientStarter<DromblerClientConfiguration>(new DromblerClientConfiguration(commandLineArgs)) {
        @Override
        protected ApplicationInstanceListener getApplicationInstanceListener() {
            return additionalArgs -> {
                // additionalArgs not handled
            };
        }

    };
    if (main.init()) {
        main.start();
    }
}
```

Source code: https://github.com/Drombler/drombler-commons/tree/master/drombler-commons-client/drombler-commons-client-startup-main

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drombler.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>drombler-commons-client-startup-main</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Javadoc: https://www.drombler.org/drombler-commons/1.0/docs/site/apidocs/org/drombler/commons/client/startup/main/package-summary.html